# .htaccess: Different AuthUserFile paths for different hosts

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am developing an application that has to run both locally as well as on a remote server. One directory is protected using an `htpasswd` file. This how I have to define the path to the `htpasswd` file in the `htaccess` file:

```
AuthUserFile ../app/some-folder/.htpasswd
```

Unfortunately the `app` folder is required on the server, but I don't have that locally. Instead, the path has to look like this:

```
AuthUserFile /Volumes/some/very/long/path/some-folder/.htpasswd
```

Is it possible to us en if/else statement to switch this AuthUserFile path according to the current host (**Edit:** Or better yet, don't require any authentication locally)? Or is there another workaround to make this file work on both my local and the remote host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. I put this in my `.htaccess`:

```
AuthName "Protected"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

This allows any connections made from the local IP to go through without entering a password. Not perfect, but works in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache 2.4+ you can use the `If` directive with `%{HTTP_HOST}` in `.htaccess`.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'localhost'">
AuthUserFile /development-path/.htpasswd
</If>

<Else>
AuthUserFile /production-path/.htpasswd
</Else>
```